# simple trigger for duplicate fullname not working,

Tags: salesforce

In student123__C  detail page there are 3 fields:  `firstname__c. lastname__c, middlename__c`. I need to write a trigger to check "if a person is entering the same values then, throw an error that "duplicate contact found".

Example: 1st record I entered as  "  Siva Naga Raju " so if am again entering this same name then it should throw an error.

For that i created a forumla field   called TOTALNAME__C  ( firstname__c + lastname__c + middlename__c).  upto here ok.   But trigger not firing, intially i worte bulk trigger, but its not firing, so i wrote a simple trigger then, it is also not firing,   please some boby help me. thanks in advance.

```
trigger duplicatefullname on student123__c (before insert, before update) {

    string name;
    list<student123__c> databasenames;
    for (student123__c stu : trigger.new) {
        name = stu.firstname__c + stu.lastname__c + stu.middlename__c;
        databasenames = [select totalname__C from student123__c where totalname__C = :name];
        if (databasenames.size() > 0)
            stu.adderror('another person with duplicate full name found');

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, formula doesn't store any value. Formula is executed only when you retrieve it.

A formula is similar to an equation that is executed at run time.